# Vectorize Image Projection with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, projection

I want to vectorize the following using numpy in the interest of efficiency but I'm finding it hard to think about and I'm not sure how to begin.

```
import numpy as np

imageA = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5)) # Some image
imageB = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5)) # Some other image
transformation = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3)) # Some transformation matrix

out_image = imageB.copy()
for y in range(imageB.shape[0]):
    for x in range(imageB.shape[1]):
        u, v, w = transformation @ np.array([x, y, 1])
        x_p, y_p = u/w, v/w

        if x_p >= 0 and x_p < imageA.shape[1] and y_p >= 0 and y_p < imageA.shape[0]:
            out_image[y, x] = imageA[int(y_p), int(x_p)]
```

Comment: Post complete test code to play with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Although not complete I was able to make some progress on this. What helped me the most was getting familiar with numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules which specifies how the dimensions for these operations must match up. If anyone has any tips or improvements I would love to hear them.

```
import numpy as np

imageA = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5)) # Some image
imageB = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5)) # Some other image
transformation = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3)) # Some transformation matrix

# Create matrix of indexes
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(imageB.shape[1]), np.arange(imageB.shape[0]), indexing='xy')
indexes = np.append(x[:,:, np.newaxis], y[:, :, np.newaxis], axis=2)

# Create homogeneous x, y coordinates
trans_indexes = np.append(indexes, np.ones((indexes.shape[0], indexes.shape[1], 1)), axis=2)

# Transform homogeneous coordinates
uvw = np.matmul(transformation, trans_indexes[:, :, :, np.newaxis]).reshape(trans_indexes.shape)
uv = uvw[:, :, :2] / uvw[:, :, 2, np.newaxis]
```